# Factoring the third degree polynomial $x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x + 12$ using long division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, cubics

I am sure there is a better strategy that someone smarter than me would use, but I am not that person.

I am trying to factor$$x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x + 12 .$$

I do not know how, so I attempt to guess with long division. I cheat and look at the answer so find out one of the factors to save myself time, so I try $x - 2$.

I am not sure how to type out long division, but I get$$ (x - 2)  \mid (x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x + 12) .$$

So I know I can have an $x^2$ for how many times $x$ goes into the leading term.

Subtracting it all, I am left with$$ (x - 2  ) \mid (-x^2 - 4x + 12) .$$

I know that the leading term goes into the inner leading term $-x$ times or however you say that.$$ (x - 2 ) \mid  (- 2x + 12) .$$

Now $-2$:$$ (x - 2 ) \mid 8 .$$

Now I do not know what to do, how did this go so wrong? I have $x^2 - x -2$ on top, and I have a remainder of $8$. This cannot be right; I cheated, so I know that this should be a factor.

Comment: The easiest way is: $( x^3 - 3x^2 ) - ( 4x - 12 ) = x^2 ( x - 3 ) - 4 ( x - 3 ) = ( x^2 - 4 ) ( x - 3 )$

Comment: $x - 2  |   - 2x + 12$ should be $x - 2  |   - 6x + 12$. There are 3 minuses at that step :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first term, upon division: $x^2$ is correct $\large\checkmark$ (in the quotient), leaving

> $$ x - 2  |  -x^2 - 4x + 12\quad\large\checkmark$$
>
> I know that the leading term goes into the inner leading term $-x$ times or however you say that.
>
> $$ x - 2  |   - 2x + 12 \quad \longleftarrow \text{error}$$

Here you subtracted incorrectly: We should have $x^2 - x$ in the quotient, that's correct, but multiplying $-x(x - 2) = -x^2 + 2x$

So when we subtract, we subtract, from $(-x^2 - 4x + 12) - (-x^2 + 2x) = -6x + 12$.

Now, we have $$ x -2 \mid -6x + 12$$ and so our ongoing quotient becomes $x^2 - x  {\bf - 6}$

which, leaves a zero remainder since $-6(x-2) = -6x + 12$, as desired.

So...we have that $$\frac{x^3 - 3x^2 -4x + 12}{x - 2} = x^2 - x - 6$$

Or, that is,  $$x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x + 12 = (x -2)(x^2 - x - 6) = (x-2)(x +2)(x - 3)$$

Comment: Very nice write up +1

Answer (score 1):

When you subtracted $(-x)(x-2)$ you should have gotten $-6x+12$.  You dropped a sign there.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Salmon's comment points out, the easiest thing to try first to factor a cubic polynomial is to try to pair off the terms and see if they share a common factor.  If paired off in the order in which they are written, this becomes

$$x^2(x-3)-4(x-3)$$

or if the odd and even exponents are paired together

$$x(x^2-4)-3(x^2-4)$$

Then simply take out the common factor.

Of course, this won't always work, when it doesn't, the method of guessing roots is known as the [rational root theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)  First you'll want to try plugging in factors of the constant term to see if you get zero.  $\pm1$ is the easiest to check, then in this case you'd also have $\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm6$ and $\pm12$.  If those all failed, you'd want to test any of those values divided by a factor of the leading term.  However, since your leading term is $1$, there isn't anything extra to test here.  If you find one root, you should be able to handle the remaining quadratic.  I doubt you'll be expected to factor any cubic polynomials with no rational roots, possibly excepting the form

$$x^3\pm a$$

at which point you could use the formula for the sum or difference of cubes even if $a$ is not a perfect cube.

Finally, although it's not foolproof, if you suspect a polynomial is a multiple of $x-2$, then plugging in $2$ should yield $0$.  Since you're dividing by $x-2$, your remainder at each step should also be a multiple of $x-2$.  Testing your polynomials at each step reveals

$$2^3-3(2)^2-4(2)+12=8-12-8+12=0$$
$$-(2)^2-4(2)+12=-4-8+12=0$$
$$-2(2)+12=-4+12=8$$

This implies there was an error in the remainder $-2x+12$

Comment: I don't really follow the first two things you did, it doesn't look correct and I can't make sense of it. If you factor out terms from two different sets you can just rearrange them in any order?

Comment: @Jordan You can rearrange sums in any order.  And factoring is basically just using the distributive property in reverse.  So for the first one I factored out $x^2$ from the first 2 terms and $-4$ from the last 2.  The next step would be to factor out $x-3$ to get $(x-3)(x^2-4)$.